# (Galois)group of order max$\{m,n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $p, q ∈ K[X]$ coprime with deg $p = m$, deg $q = n$, and suppose $f := \frac{p}{q} ∈ K(X)\setminus K$.

Supposedly, then, $K(X)/K(f)$ is an algebraic extension of degree max$\{m,n\}$. To show this we could perhaps invoke the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory. Namely, if $K(f) = K(X)^G$ for some finite $G ≤\text{Aut}(K(X))$, then the Fundamental Theorem states that $[K(X) :K(f)] = \#G$, which is finite. (Therefore the extension is immediately algebraic.) This group would obviously depend on $p, q$ and hence on $m, n$, so we could write $G_{m,n}$. But what group has order max$\{m, n\}$??

Comment: I don’t entirely understand what your question is. Are you just trying to find the Galois group of this field extension in general? If so, I’m a bit confused by your emphasis on $m, n$ as opposed to $p,q$.

Comment: I'm trying to show that it's algebraic and that its degree is max$\{m,n\}$. What I wrote down is just one possible strategy I could think of.

Comment: You can assume WLOG that $n\geq m$ since if $n<m$ then you can replace $f$ with $1/f$. One method would then be to simply show that $\{1,X,\ldots,X^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $K(X)$ over $K(f)$. Showing it spans $K(X)$ is relatively straight forward. Showing it is linearly independent is a bit more tedious and relies on the fact that $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

Comment: The extension is not Galois (in general) so that approach will not work. The easiest approach (in my opinion) is to observe that $X$ is a root of $p(t) - f q(t) \in K(f)[t]$ which has the right degree, then show that this polynomial is irreducible by using Gauss's lemma (basically straightforward).

Comment: I get it _up to_ the reference to Gauss's Lemma, because - as I know it - it shows that if a polynomial is reducible over the field of fractions of a UFD, it is also reducible over the UFD itself. However, all the UFDs here are fields already, so the lemma tells us that if the polynomial is reducible over $Q(K(f)) = K(f)$, it is also reducible over $K(f)$....

Comment: The UFD in question is not $K(f)$ but rather $K[f]$.

Comment: Aaah yes, then $\deg_f(g) = 1$, so it must be irreducible over $K[f]$, so by Gauss, it must also be irreducible over $K(f)$. Thus, $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $K(f)$, and the result follows.